# How to calculate the value share of some sub-category (level 4) out of its corresponding category/parent (level 3)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, categories

I have to calculate the level 4 categories value share of their parent level 3 category.
This is an example of my data frame:
The level is given by the code at the start of each name in the category column, as example: "01 abc" is level 1 and "01.01.01.00 abc" is level 4

```
df <- data.frame(Store = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                           "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
                 Category = c("01 Fruits & Vegetables", "01.01 Vegetables", "01.01.03 Carrots", "01.01.03.00 Baby Carrots", 
                              "01.01.03.01 Purple Carrots", "01.01.03.01 Sliced Carrots", "01.01.05 Spinach", 
                              "01.01.05.00 Cubes Packed", "01.01.05.01 Choped", "01.01.05.02 Leafs", 
                              "01 Fruits & Vegetables", "01.01 Vegetables", "01.01.03 Carrots", 
                              "01.01.03.00 Baby Carrots", "01.01.03.01 Purple Carrots", "01.01.03.01 Sliced Carrots", 
                              "01.01.05 Spinach", "01.01.05.00 Cubes Packed", "01.01.05.01 Choped", 
                              "01.01.05.02 Leafs"),
                 Value = c(1092030, 519696, 123991, 
                           2116, 8087, 33946, 43059, 7410, 
                           41, 24411, 1289392, 654442, 140990, 
                           11351, 2235, 48679, 64681, 9553, 
                           2921, 36109),
                 Level = c(1,2,3,4,4,4,3,4,4,4))
> df
   Store                   Category   Value Level
1      A     01 Fruits & Vegetables 1092030     1
2      A           01.01 Vegetables  519696     2
3      A           01.01.03 Carrots  123991     3
4      A   01.01.03.00 Baby Carrots    2116     4
5      A 01.01.03.01 Purple Carrots    8087     4
6      A 01.01.03.01 Sliced Carrots   33946     4
7      A           01.01.05 Spinach   43059     3
8      A   01.01.05.00 Cubes Packed    7410     4
9      A         01.01.05.01 Choped      41     4
10     A          01.01.05.02 Leafs   24411     4
11     B     01 Fruits & Vegetables 1289392     1
12     B           01.01 Vegetables  654442     2
13     B           01.01.03 Carrots  140990     3
14     B   01.01.03.00 Baby Carrots   11351     4
15     B 01.01.03.01 Purple Carrots    2235     4
16     B 01.01.03.01 Sliced Carrots   48679     4
17     B           01.01.05 Spinach   64681     3
18     B   01.01.05.00 Cubes Packed    9553     4
19     B         01.01.05.01 Choped    2921     4
20     B          01.01.05.02 Leafs   36109     4
```

EDIT:
I've tried the following code so far but the value share it's completely wrong.
I want value share of each level 4 category out of its corresponding level 3 category (parent) ONLY for 4 out of 3 and and just put 0 or 100 or empty for levels 1:3

```
dt1<-df %>%
  mutate(Level3_Category = ifelse(Level == 3, Category, 
                                  gsub("(^\\d{2}\\.\\d{2})(\\..*)?", "\\1", Category, perl = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(Store, Category, Level3_Category) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Level3_Category) %>%
  mutate(share_percentage = Value / sum(Value) * 100)
```

Example of what I want to the result to look like:

| Store | Category | Value | Level | Value Share % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 Fruits & Vegetables | 1092030 | 1 | 100 |
| A | 01.01 Vegetables | 519696 | 2 | 100 |
| A | 01.01.03 Carrots | 123991 | 3 | 100 |
| A | 01.01.03.00 Baby Carrots | 2116 | 4 | 1,70 |
| A | 01.01.03.01 Purple Carrots | 8087 | 4 | 6,52 |
| A | 01.01.03.01 Sliced Carrots | 33946 | 4 | 27,37 |

Comment: Are you also grouping by Store?  Are those values in the expected correct i.e. based on your input data or is it just dummy

Comment: I tried grouping by store to and it did make a difference and the expected it's just a dummy to show you what I want the result to be in the value share column